# HD Video Sticks

Tags: linux, browser, media

I have HD video, which I play through browser. Whenever I try to play it with "low quality" and "medium quality", the video plays smoothly.

But when I select "High quality", the same video sticks while playing. All videos are fully buffered before playing. What can be the cause for this?

The browser is Mozilla. I experienced the same behavior for YouTube videos also.

Comment: Consider adding more information about what type of video you're playing (Flash, HTML5?), your hardware, your specific browser and plugin versions etc.

Comment: Have you considered playing your video with a dedicated, separate media player? Those are usually a better way to get smoothless playback. Also, does a HD video actually play smoothly with a dedicated player? Check if your video card, video driver and CPU do actually allow you to play these videos smoothly. Buffering has nothing to do with playback speed, buffering only helps with network issues, you still need to have good enough hardware and acceleration in order to play heavy videos smoothly.